# SQL - count unique first occurrence of value

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a log table with user activities.
I'm trying to create a query that will show unique users entries and new users entries.

Sample data:

```
| uid | act | tm                       |
| --- | --- | ------------------------ |
| 1   | l   | 2019-01-02T00:00:00.000Z |
| 1   | l   | 2019-01-05T00:00:00.000Z |
| 2   | l   | 2019-02-02T00:00:00.000Z |
| 1   | l   | 2019-02-03T00:00:00.000Z |
| 2   | l   | 2019-02-04T00:00:00.000Z |
| 3   | l   | 2019-02-05T00:00:00.000Z |
| 1   | l   | 2019-03-02T00:00:00.000Z |
| 2   | l   | 2019-03-02T00:00:00.000Z |
| 3   | l   | 2019-03-02T00:00:00.000Z |
| 4   | l   | 2019-03-02T00:00:00.000Z |
```

The first part is easy : `count(distinct(uid)) as tot_users`

But is there a way to do second part - count users that appeared in that period but not before...

Here is what I got so far -
https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/8EXsih1VAL1iWXKeauPQiB/1

---

For the future reference, I've updated db-fiddle with 2 proposed solutions. Both work nicely:

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/8EXsih1VAL1iWXKeauPQiB/6

```
SELECT
        to_char( date_trunc('month', tm), 'YYYY-MM') as mnth,
        count(uid) as tot_entries, 
        COUNT(DISTINCT uid) as tot_users,

        COUNT(DISTINCT 
                CASE 
                    WHEN DATE_TRUNC('month', min_tm) = DATE_TRUNC('month', tm) 
                    THEN uid 
                END) AS new_users

FROM (SELECT l.*, MIN(tm) OVER(PARTITION BY uid) min_tm FROM logs l) x 
GROUP BY mnth
ORDER BY mnth;


SELECT 
        to_char(date_trunc('month', l1.tm), 'YYYY-MM') mnth,
        count(l1.uid) tot_entries,
        count(DISTINCT l1.uid) tot_users,

        count(DISTINCT 
                CASE
                    WHEN NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                                        FROM logs l2
                                        WHERE l2.uid = l1.uid
                                            AND to_char(date_trunc('month', l2.tm), 'YYYY-MM') < to_char(date_trunc('month', l1.tm), 'YYYY-MM')) 
                    THEN
                          l1.uid
                END) new_users

FROM logs l1
GROUP BY mnth
ORDER BY mnth;
```

Comment: I copied the sample data from the fiddle to your question. Would you please also edit your question to show us what your expected output would look like?

Comment: Unique user entires == new user entries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a window function in a subquery to compute the timestamp of the first log entry of each user, like:

```
SELECT l.*, MIN(tm) OVER(PARTITION BY uid) min_tm FROM logs l
```

Then, you can analyze the results in an outer query. When the date of the first log entry of a user belongs to the analyzis interval, you can count him as a *new user*.

Assuming the parameters `:start_tm` and `:end_tm` represent the start and end of the analyzis period, you would go:

```
SELECT
    COUNT(DISTINCT uid) as tot_users,
    COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN min_tm >= :start_tm AND min_tm < :end_tm THEN uid END) AS tot_new_users
FROM (SELECT l.*, MIN(tm) OVER(PARTITION BY uid) min_tm FROM logs l) x 
WHERE tm >= :start_tm AND tm < :end_tm
```

---

If you need to aggregate by months:

```
SELECT
    DATE_TRUNC('month', tm) AS my_month,
    COUNT(DISTINCT uid) as tot_users,
    COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN DATE_TRUNC('month', min_tm) = DATE_TRUNC('month', tm) THEN uid END) AS tot_new_users
FROM (SELECT l.*, MIN(tm) OVER(PARTITION BY uid) min_tm FROM logs l) x 
GROUP BY my_month
ORDER BY my_month
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I don't want to specify start time and end time, I'd like to do it by monthly periods

Comment: @xims: ah ok, I updated my answer accordingly. Pls note that window functions usually perform better than the equivalent subqueries or aggregated queries (and are also less verbose!)

Comment: please edit to make it  "logs l", otherwise it's not working

Answer (score 1):

You can use conditional aggregation. In a `CASE` expression check for the existence of a log entry for the same user in a previous month. Unless you found such an entry return the user's id. Use that expression as the argument to `count()`.

```
SELECT to_char(date_trunc('month', l1.tm), 'YYYY-MM') mnth,
       count(l1.uid) tot_entries,
       count(DISTINCT l1.uid) tot_users,
       count(DISTINCT CASE
                        WHEN NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                                                FROM logs l2
                                                WHERE l2.uid = l1.uid
                                                      AND to_char(date_trunc('month', l2.tm), 'YYYY-MM') < to_char(date_trunc('month', l1.tm), 'YYYY-MM')) THEN
                          l1.uid
                      END) new_users
       FROM logs l1
       GROUP BY mnth
       ORDER BY mnth;
```

Answer (score 0):

you might use either the having clause or a self-join. You mentioned a period ,so I am not sure about the exact filter but let's assume it is a simple case you can do something like this

```
select 
   uid, 
   case when mintm<'2019-03-02T00:00:00.000Z' --cutoff
      then 'old' else 'new' 
   end flag
from (
select uid, min(tm) mintm from table
group by uid ) as first_logins
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I don't want to specify cutoff time, I'd like it to be by periods